# Not able to connect multiple instance of a Spring boot JMS client application running in docker to IBM Mq instance

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2

HI I am running a Spring boot JMS application in docker container in aws ec2 environment. My application running in two containers . While creating a connection to IBM Mq only one instance is connecting while the other is giving the connection error with code -

> ERROR org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer
>   - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'test.test.queue' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=1689,
>   maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue
>   manager 'OM_QMGR' with connection mode 'Client' and host name
>   'test.test.ibmcloud.com(1415)'.; nested exception is
>   com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode
>   '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').

My POM has this dependency -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

with listener methods -

```
@JmsListener(destination = TEST_QUEUE)
public void subscribeOmsQueue(String message)
```